# My mac would not boot so I formatted the drive and now it has no OS

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup

So there is a whole other backstory as to why my computer would not boot and why I needed to format the drive. The only thing I need to know is how can I install an OS to my computer. I tried CMD-R, but it only gives me the option to upgrade to Lion and when I click to do that it tells me that Lion is no longer available. I do not have access to other macs so I don't know how I can install an operating system on my own. Oh and my computer is one of the 2010 Macbook Pros.

Comment: Lion should still be available. If you do an internet recovery it will download and install the version of the OS that was current when your machine was released instead of the current OS now. Please try again. It should allow you to install Lion.

Comment: I have tried multiple times and it keeps telling me Lion is not available. Could it be because my system time is very wrong?

Comment: That could be a problem. If your MacBook is trying to download over a secure HTTPS connection, having the wrong time could make your MacBook think Apple's certificates are invalid. Can you fix the time?

Comment: Internet Recovery (⌥⌘R) will obtain the time from Apple's time server as opposed to the Recovery HD which does not afaik —cc @Alistair

Answer (score 1):

When you formatted your drive, you must have been "standing" on some other boot drive ... backup (??). That said, clone its OS to your newly formatted drive. Use Carbon Copy Cloner ... the best. If you don't already have CCC, get it and install it on the drive where you "stood" to do your original formatting.